# get Link name from a list of links using javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I am getting link values using an arraylist before diplaying then onto my Popup jsp. I am supposed to get the text once the link is clicked and pass it to parent page... No matter what I do the value getting passed to the Parent Jsp is only the first value in the array:

My **POPUP.Jsp**:

```
<%
    ArrayList all = Locations.getAllLocations();
    int size = all.size();
%>  
<%
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        ArrayList one = (ArrayList) all.get(i);
%>
    <tr style="height:30px; padding:4px;">
        <td><div align="center"><a href="" onclick="getTownValue()" id="tname"><%=(String) one.get(0)%></a></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(1)%></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(2)%></div></td>
    </tr>
<% }%>
```

The display is working fine but whenever I click on the links I only get the first value in the array. What should I do?

**Edit**

My JAvascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTownValue() {
        var t = document.getElementById('tname').innerHTML; //for innerhtml
        window.opener.document.form1.location.value = t;
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, You have to use this keyword to get individual value of link.

Use below code :

```
<%
ArrayList all = Locations.getAllLocations();
int size = all.size();
%>  
<%
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ArrayList one = (ArrayList) all.get(i);
%>
<tr style="height:30px; padding:4px;">
    <td><div align="center"><a href="" onclick="getTownValue(this)" id="tname">           <%=(String) one.get(0)%></a></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(1)%></div></td>
    <td><div align="center"><%=(String) one.get(2)%></div></td>
</tr>
<% }%>
```

Please Replace this Javascript :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function getTownValue(ths) {
    var t = ths.innerHTML; //for innerhtml
    window.opener.document.form1.location.value = t;
    window.close();
  }
  </script>
```

Here i used "ths" to get value for individual link.
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have first value in the array, **because all your links have the same id "tname"**. And when you click on link - **javascript fill found all links with id "tname" and get the first**.

Comment: Oh! Ok, is there a way to assign a unique id to each link?

Comment: Please, check this -  id="tname+<%=(String) one.get(0)%>" You can assign unique iteration id